# Reference error in string match algorithm

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I have created UDF for string matching percentage (0-1) between two string columns and I am facing this error when I execute the below query.I want to execute this code to get the name matching algorithm to show the probability algorithm from 0-1 value.I have created two functions and defined the two string columns in this function.

```js
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `rep-ds-us.nboorla.similarity`(name STRING, to_name STRING) RETURNS INT64 LANGUAGE js AS """
/*
 * Data Quality Function - Fuzzy Matching
 * dq_fm_LevenshteinDistance
 * Based off of https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927
 * input: Two strings to compare the edit distance of.
 * returns: Integer of the edit distance.
 */
var a = in_a.toLowerCase();
var b = in_b.toLowerCase();
  
if(a.length == 0) return b.length; 
if(b.length == 0) return a.length;
var matrix = [];
// increment along the first column of each row
var i;
for(i = 0; i <= b.length; i++){
  matrix[i] = [i];
}
// increment each column in the first row
var j;
for(j = 0; j <= a.length; j++){
  matrix[0][j] = j;
}
// Fill in the rest of the matrix
for(i = 1; i <= b.length; i++){
  for(j = 1; j <= a.length; j++){
    if(b.charAt(i-1) == a.charAt(j-1)){
      matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1];
    } else {
      matrix[i][j] = 
        Math.min(matrix[i-1][j-1] + 1, // substitution
        Math.min(matrix[i][j-1] + 1, // insertion
        matrix[i-1][j] + 1)); // deletion
    }
  }
}
return matrix[b.length][a.length];
""";

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `rep-ds-us.nboorla.conf`(name STRING, to_name STRING) AS (
/*
 * Data Quality Function - Fuzzy Matching
 * dq_fm_ldist_ratio
 * input: Two strings to compare.
 * returns: The Levenshtein similarity ratio.
 */
(LENGTH(name) + LENGTH(to_name) -  `rep-ds-us.nboorla.similarity`(name, to_name)) 
  / (LENGTH(name) + LENGTH(to_name))
);

select t1.name,t2.to_name,`rep-ds-us.nboorla.conf`(t1.name,t2.to_name)
from `rep-ds-us.r4e_mongo.ratings` t1 
 JOIN `rep-ds-us.r4e_mongo.mongo_repbiz_request_reviews` t2 on t2.id=t1.id 
 limit 10
```

but it is giving me below error

```
Query error: ReferenceError: in_a is not defined at UDF$1(STRING, STRING) line 9, columns 8-9 at [52:1]
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is giving me below error
>
> Query error: ReferenceError: in_a is not defined at UDF$1(STRING, STRING) line 9, columns 8-9 at [52:1]
> Am I missing something?

You should at least fix the signature for your first function as in below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `rep-ds-us.nboorla.similarity`(in_a STRING, in_b STRING) RETURNS INT64 LANGUAGE js AS """
```

Note; above answers your specific current issue and may not address any future ones related to the code you use.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!! i get the issue again after the changes!!!`Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null at UDF$1(STRING, STRING) line 9, columns 13-14 at [52:1]`

Comment: just don't pass the null to the function!

Comment: can you help me find where i defined null function

Comment: it is either t1.name or t2.to_name - so you need to check respective table if they have null for respective columns :o) meantime to avoid this scenarion you can replace \`rep-ds-us.nboorla.conf\`(t1.name,t2.to_name)with \`rep-ds-us.nboorla.conf\`(IFNULL(t1.name, ''),IFNULL(t2.to_name, '')), so instead of passing null(s) you will pass empty string

Comment: glad it helped. see you in next questions :o)